# Strategies to improve performance of interpreter

Tags: interpreter, portability, jit, multiplatform

Some languages like Java, C or C++ are very portable/multi-platforms. But why is that? what are the strategies that can be used in the interpreter that will improve the general performance of the interpretation? I thought about JIT (just in time compilation). Since it translates one instruction once and then reuses it whenever it appears again. But JIT can be used to justify multi-platform? What are the other strategies?

Answer (score 1):

> Some languages like Java, C or C++ are very portable/multi-platforms. But why is that?

They are portable but in different ways. Java is binary portable in the sense that the same executable binaries can run on many architectures. This is achieved using interpretation or JIT compilation. C/C++ is source portable in the sense that there are compilers for many platforms and so you can compile the same source code to produce different binaries for different platforms.

> what are the strategies that can be used in the interpreter that will
>   improve the general performance of the interpretation?

There has been a substantial amount of research on improving the performance of interpretation and one can write a very thick book about it. I recommend reading the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)) page about interpreters as an introduction.

> Since it translates one instruction once and then reuses it whenever
>   it appears again.

A JIT compiler translates a number of instructions together, not just one. For example, a JIT compiler may compile one function at a time.